# JavaFX ArrayList/Observablelist displayed in TableView column or ListView

Tags: arraylist, javafx

```
ArrayList<String> dblist = new ArrayList<String>();
ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dblist);
//ListView<String> listview;
```

How do I display the value of dblist on screen in TableView's column or ListView in Javafx? I don't understand the use of setCellFactory, please explain if you use this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html):

```
ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>(names);
```

Comment: Ok cool. Use listview.setItems(list); after adding new values to the arraylist. Thanks.